# check url without http and ".com"

Tags: regex

I would like to check if the given url is valid.

It should accept:

```
www.gmail.com
```

and should reject:

```
www.gmail
```

I tried using this `/((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/`

It works but if the given input is `www.gmail` it does accepts it.

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/aabanaag/VktaX/

Comment: This seems to me like a duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url Did you check that out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 0):

try this .It is working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        var pattern = new RegExp("^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
        if (pattern.test(url)) {
            alert("Url is valid");
            return true;
        } 
            alert("Url is not valid!");
            return false;

    }
</script>
```

In jQuery

you can use url validation

```
<input type="text" class="url"/>
```

Comment: @Dreyfus15 did you checked this

Comment: tried it. but "www.gmail.com" works even "www.gmail" is accepted. It must not be accepted since "www.gmail" is not a valid url.

Comment: @Dreyfus15 i specified 2 patterns which one you used

Comment: I tried both. see http://jsfiddle.net/aabanaag/VktaX/ link though it is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery Validate plugin for that.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});
```

You can find about it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url)

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem:

found this while googling over the internet.

```
 /^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}[0-9A-Za-z\.\-]*\.[0-9A-Za-z\.\-]*$/


var pattern1 = /^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}[0-9A-Za-z\.\-]*\.[0-9A-Za-z\.\-]*$/;

var result = "www.gmail";

if (pattern1.test(result)) {
    console.log("test");
}else{
    console.log("fail");
}
```

It works best.